# How to make nested group in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Assume there's a data in Mongo! There are a few projects, and there're managers, to who the problems are assigned. Each problem is assigned to different people as the project has different parts.
How can one compute the number, each assignee has been assigned within a project.
For example:

```
{
    "Project A": {
            "Ted":10,
            "Matt":5
            },
    "Project B": {
            "Mary":3,
            "Hector":30
            }
}
```

The following writes the sum but doesn't group it:

```
db.test.issues.group({
    "key": {
        "project": true
        "assignee":true
    },
    "initial": {
        "countassignee": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        prev.countassignee++;
    }
});
```

It will return as:

```
{
{
"project": "Project A",
"countassignee":10,
"assignee":"Ted" 
}
....
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Please clarify.  In particular what have you tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! It doesn't seem like the best answer, but it'll do!
first define a cursor sorting by projects

```
var cursor = db.test.find().sort({projects:1});
```

a list for the counter:

```
var asgn_nums = {};
```

and a variable holding project name;:

```
var project = '0';
```

Here counts for each project:

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var issue = cursor.next();
    var p = issue.project;
    if(p != project)
    {
        if(project != '0'){
            print(project+":");
            printjson(asgn_nums);
        }
        project = p;
        asgn_nums = {};
    }
    if(issue.assignee != null)
    {
        if (asgn_nums[issue.assignee] == null)
            asgn_nums[issue.assignee] = 1;
        else
            asgn_nums[issue.assignee]+= 1;
    }
    if(!cursor.hasNext())
    {
        print(project+":");
        printjson(asgn_nums);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data sample provide by you is pretty confusing. its Project A and project B supposed to be different document. 
I believe the best use of group is to aggegrate within a collections, if you want to count within a doucment you may use javascript.